# Is there any way to inter communicate with modules in boilerplatejs?

Tags: event-handling, knockout.js, boilerplatejs

Regarding the [BoilerplateJs](http://boilerplatejs.org/samples/productsuite/index.html#sales) example, how should we adjust those modules to be intercommunicate in such a way once the user done any change to one module, the other related modules should be updated with that change done.

For example, if there is a module to retrieve inputs from user as name and sales and another module to update those retrieved data in a table or a graph, can you explain with some example ,how those inter connection occurs considering event handling?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In BoilerplateJS, each of your module will have it's own moduleContext object. This module context object contains two methods 'listen' and 'notify'. Have a look at the context class at '/src/core/context.js' for more details.

The component that need to 'listen' to the event, should register for the event by specifying the name of the event and callback handler. Component that raise the event should use 'notify' method to let others know something interesting happened (optionally passing a parameter).

Get an update of the latest BoilerplateJS code from [GitHub](https://github.com/ectechno/boilerplatejs). I just committed changes with making clickCounter a composite component where 'clickme component' raising an event and 'lottery component' listening to the event to respond.

Code for notifying the Event:

```
moduleContext.notify('LOTTERY_ACTIVITY', this.numberOfClicks());
```

Code for listening to the Event:

```
moduleContext.listen("LOTTERY_ACTIVITY", function(activityNumber) {
   var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
   self.hasWon(randomNum === activityNumber);
});
```

Comment: btw.. BoilerplateJS uses a slightly modified version of [pubsub.js](https://github.com/federico-lox/pubsub.js) implementation from Federico Lucignano behind the scene.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at using a Publish-Subscribe library, such as [Amplify](http://amplifyjs.com/api/pubsub/).  Using this technique it is easy for one module to act as a publisher of events and others to register as subscribers, listening and responding to these events in a highly decoupled manner.

As you are already using Knockout you might be interested in first trying Ryan Niemeyer's [knockout-postbox](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox#readme) plugin first. More background on this library is [available here](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/using-ko-native-pubsub.html) including [a demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/mg3hj/).  You can always switch to Amplify later if you require.